# PhonegapBuild plugins

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm new to using plugins with Phonegap, I know how to connect the plugin with the app via config.xml but I can't figure out where I'm supposed to put the js that comes with the plug in. I want to change the status bar appearance so I integrated this: https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin/tree/0944be5c9f96ca0e39e0079f46ffc37894a586cd but to change the content colour I need to copy that js to somewhere, and where is that? In the index.html, any special js file? And is it the same process for every other plugin too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the library files for plugin will be bundled by default into plugins folder. For using the plugin, the related javascript you have to call after deviceready event. deviceready event is fired when Cordova/phonegap is fully loaded.Once the event fires, you can safely make calls to Cordova APIs.

Ex:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByName("red");
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll try it as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

did you use the command 
1.

```
 cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin
```

if the platform is added in prior delete the folder also delete json file(ex: android.json,ios.json) inside plugins folder and
 run below command after adding plugin 
2.

```
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: Commands? I'm using Phonegap Build. Not standalone PhoneGap SDK.

Comment: yeah, phonegap build provides instructions to setup the plugins manually,but installing the plugins via command makes your work easy and there is no need of dragging the files manually.Try, to work using command prompt or terminal if it fails we will do via manually